# Spring & Mockito - ignore transitive dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, spring, mockito

I have a layered application that looks like this:

```
@PreAuthorize('isAuthenticated()')
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    MyService service;
}

@Service 
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyDao dao;
}

public interface MyDao {
}

@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {
}
```

I want to test the AOP-dependent `@PreAuthorize` annotation, so I use the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` which creates a test `AuthenticationManager` and `MyController`.

If the `@ContextConfiguration` does not include any bean matching `MyService`, test initialization fails because it can't resolve the bean.

If I didn't need AOP, I would use Mockito test runner and inject `Mockito.mock(MyService.class)`. But if I try and do it with spring runner, again my test fails because it can't resolve `MyDao` for the service (even though the service a mock).

I definitely don't want to mock the whole object graph. I'd rather it stopped on the mocked service. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MyService should implement an interface, and you should mock the interface instead of the class. Then you won't need a DAO implementation. You might also, perhaps, be running into a similar issue that I faced while trying to test a JAX-RS resource class in Jersey. The problem is how to deploy a single bean into a Spring container but mock its dependencies. I wrote a [blog post](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-testing-of-jersey-resource.html) on it that might help you out if this is the problem you're facing. In particular, the [final solution](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-testing-of-jersey-resource.html#d0e53) may be of help.

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there any way I could avoid that? What if I'm fairly happy with having one and only implementation and don't feel like creating an interface for each and every bean?

Comment: @Konrad: Regardless of how many implementations you have or plan to have, best practice is to always code to interfaces, thus separating contract from implementation details. That said, the specific problem you were having is that when you mock a class with mockito, it uses cglib to create a dynamic subclass. When you tried to use it as a spring bean, the subclass still inherited the `@Autowired` property from `MyService` and so Spring still tried to wire it. Anything that gets you around that will also work. Switching to constructor injection would work, for instance.

Comment: That isn't really a good advice. You don't want to have interfaces everywhere - for example Services that contain only business logic and aren't tied to some specific technology, there is no point to have mirrored implementation and interface.

Comment: @TadasŠubonis: If you have a better solution, then by all means suggest it. I believe I covered all the bases at the time, though this question is over 2 years old.